# Рентабельность генерации контента в ajax запросах

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, vue.js

Сложилась такая ситуация, что начал программировать сайт на jquery+php(около 4 месяцев назад), проводя всё больше времени за кодом пришло понимание что, всё что я делаю не имеет ни какой масштабируемости и вариативности. После познакомился с ООП в php, моей радости не было предела. На моём сайте куча таблиц с редактируемыми td-шками и прочими сложностями напрямую связанные с базой и чтобы не строить одни и те же ячейки по сто раз(часто от таблицы к таблице ячейки повторяются) при загрузке страницы я обрабатываю любую таблицу ajax запросом, где на обратной стороне генерится html код через классы php просто передав ему название таблицы и id-шники th. Мне так понравился данный способ, что я теперь хочу генерить любой сложный контент напрямую зависящий от базы в ajax запросах. Есть ли у данного способа минусы или любые более адекватные аналоги? Немного почитал про vue.js мне очень понравилась структура построения данных, но js код не может связаться с базой как с этим быть. Я новичок и не кидайте пожалуйста палками, буду рад любой информации и построении сложных масштабируемых проектах и какие технологии для этого подходят.

Comment: "но js код не может связаться с базой"  --- может. в vue есть компоненты работы с запросами

Comment: скорее всего, но это будет опять же ajax запрос

Comment: так, а что хочется? не ясно. для нового контента - надо взять данные откуда-то.

Comment: В первую очередь хочется убедится в правильном ли я направлении иду, я самоучка и подсказать не кому

Comment: Пока что-то не совсем понятно в чём конкретно загвоздка. Текста много и суть не ясна в итоге. Затонуло в воде повествования

Comment: my bad. 1)Стоит ли уходить от связки jquery+php в vue.js + php  и увеличится ли масштабируемость + адаптивность. 2) Можно ли вообще таким способом генерить контент на стороне Php (seo не волнует т.к это приватный личный кабинет)

Comment: мне нравится сама идея того, что я написал где то один раз а потом этот компонент могу вывести куда угодно

Comment: @АртурКузнецов В целом считается что jQ устарел и да таки стоит переписать на Vue, однако само по себе это не даст расширяемости, тут все дело в том как это написать, и на чистом js с php  вполне можно реализовать что то самописное и расширяемое. вопрос даже не в технологиях а в самой логике написанного. Однако при прочих равных Vue на порядок быстрее и технологичнее.

Comment: Дополню слова выше добавлением библы: reactjs, которая более популярна чем vue, но смысл тот же. А так, да, перейти можно. Главное правильно делать. Но это приходит с опытом

Comment: @Артур Кузнецов да, и ещё, моё мнение - не стоит (про уход от связок). Нет такого, что не написать  быстро и качественно на jQuery и его библиотеках: если хорошо организован бекенд. И главное - вы никогда не будете забивать голову фронтом, работая с jQuery + не будете делать ошибок на фронте вовсе со временем - потому что он эталон интуитивности и логичности. В общем - это касается всего, ни в коем случае не применяйте технологии ради технологий потому что "вроде круче", простота и понятность, читаемость - вот что главное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подход стандартный, вы получаете html не всей страницы, а только блока. Такой блок называется виджет.

> Есть ли у данного способа минусы

Да, есть. Вот например в вашем сервисе есть какая-то система прав ACL. Запросы в эту систему могут быть довольно тяжёлые. Для каждой загрузки виджета придётся проверять, имеет ли залогиненный юзер(который запрашивает виджет) права доступа к загружаемому контенту.

И потом, думаю врядли вы это сделали именно таким образом: правильно при загрузке построить страницу целиком готовую к работе без ajax запросов. То есть построить готовый HTML, те-же виджеты вывести в правильные места используя PHP: но иметь возможность дёргать их отдельно через ajax. Вот это топ, и отлично ложится на MVC.

Почему так правильно - потому что много запросов на бекенд на пустом месте: это плохо, это будет грузить сервер(как минимум отъестся cpu/ram/время-сетевого-пинга на подключение к БД, кешу, инициализацию общих сервисов - на каждый ajax) + это создаст неприятные впечатления у юзеров, им придётся ещё чего-то ждать, тогда как страница уже загрузилась, или наблюдать ненавистное колёсико загрузки каждый переход на новую страницу.

Поскольку вы новичок(возможно вы ещё не в курсе), порекомендую посмотреть в сторону PHP-фреймворков с базой MVC, использующих ActiveRecord и ORM : этого c головой достаточно, чтобы порядок был в коде на любом сайте, хоть масштаба фейсбука. В том числе встраивается такая вот система для виждетов - которая собирает страницу из отдельных блоков без ajax, но может каждый отдельный блок запросить отдельно (например после пользовательских действий с UI).